# Using MPMediaLibrary to add song to playlist

Tags: ios, mpmedialibrary

I am creating an app to that allows you to add a song into your music library but I can only add them to the music library. It works but I have noticed Shazam can add them to specific playlists

Do they have special access or am I completely missing something in the API?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out MPMediaPlaylist also responds to addItemWithProductID. Not just [MPMediaLibrary defaultMediaLibrary] as the documentation led me to believe.